# Is there a way to specify paths relative to the project root when creating a new file using File > New… > File?

Tags: pycharm

I’m trying to quickly create multiple files from copied string paths relative to the PyCharm project’s root directory (e.g. if the project is in C:\Users\Harvey\Projects\abc, then the path I want to create the file in is specified relative to that, e.g. dir1\file.txt should be created with full path C:\Users\Harvey\Projects\abc\dir1\file.txt) but I can’t see a good way to do this.

I can create a file relative to where I have selected in the project using the File > New… > File method by just specifying the relative path, and I can specify relative to the system Home directory by using the relative path after ~, but these aren’t what’s needed.

Any help greatly appreciated to make my workflow easier. I have considered writing code for creating the files, but this is less ideal as it would either increase the clicks to handle one file, or I’d have to create them all and then sort through matching up the file contents to the files, which would be out of order.

Comment: Is it easier to use "Project" tab, and you select your base directory. Add new file, then you just type the rest of the path?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the problem with this is the Project tab will focus on the newly-created file, so extra clicks/scrolling to return to the root directory again before creating the next file. It’s what I’m currently doing, but hoped there was a better way/shortcut. Currently creating a file from there using Alt+Insert, then focussing there again and pressing Ctrl+Home to return to root, then repeating, but just more cumbersome than I feel it could be with all of PyCharm’s shortcuts and tricks!

Comment: I do not find many (or any) use case. Your task seems better to do with automation, so having a script which creates files.